# Qt Application, focus and show/hide function

Tags: qt, focus, trayicon

I am trying to do simly functionality. 
When I click on tray icon:

```
 -A- if app is hide > show
 -B- if app is show and is NOT focus > focus it
 -C- if app is show and focus > hide
```

Very simle but if you have focus app and you click on try icon, the focus is lost and now the taskbar is focused. So the B condition is true instead of C.
So what with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assume C when the click event on the tray icon occurs very shortly after the focus out event of the main window. So you could do something like this:

```
MainWindow::focusOutEvent(...) {
    trayIcon->setJustFocussedOut(true);
    this->someQTimer->start();
}

MainWindow::focusOutDone() {
    trayIcon->setJustFocussedOut(false);
}
```

Where `MainWindow::someQTimer` is a QTimer set to singleshot mode and a very short interval (e.g. 50 milliseconds). The `setJustFocussedOut` method sets a flag in the tray icon which makes it handle a click as case C.